# Remove redirect to website when debugging in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mamp, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

It turns out it is just because I did not amend wp-options in the db to change site_url to point to localhost. Now there is no problem.

This is very dumb of me, but I can't figure out how to undo this thing I did.

I have Eclipse PDT set up on my MAC and I am also running MAMP and Xdebug. I have set up the Eclipse debug and I followed some instructions from a website earlier on to launch the application on Safari. There was an instruction to configure the debug such that instead of debug running on localhost, it redirects to my hosted site (from localhost:8888 it immediately goes to lionfish.vodien.com). I think it is preventing me from debugging properly as I do not have anything set up on lionfish.vodien.com. Everything is set up locally on my MAC.

Unfortunately I have forgotten where it is I set the link to redirect. I went through the Eclipse Preferences many times and I can't find the location for setting this. I checked MAMP and there isn't any setting there too.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: do a file search in eclipse for keywords 'lionfish.vodien.com'

Comment: Thanks Pranalee, I am very glad someone finally answered my question. I did do a search and found it in wp-config.php, I commented out the link and set localhost instead. But the solution I found an hour back was to amend the SITE_URL setting in the database under wp-options.